# Match anything except e-mail address in line

Tags: powershell

In the following lines

```
Doe, John    john.doe@example.com
Bar, Foo     foo.bar@example.com
Example, Michael (Contract Worker)     michael.example@example.com
```

How can I make a regex to return only

- `Doe, John` for line 1,
- `Bar, Foo` for line 2, and
- `Example, Michael (Contract Worker)` for line 3 while discarding only the
  e-mail addresses?

The following regex matches the e-mail addresses

```
([^\s]+)\b[@]+\b([^\s]+)
```

How can I make it the opposite?

Comment: if the spaces between the email address and the names are tabs OR more-than-one-space, you can split on that and take the 1st part. if you _must_ use a regex, then have it stop when it reaches the tabs.

Comment: Is the email always going to be present, and always the last part of the string?

Comment: Yes. The email will always be present at the last part of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems easier to capture everything before email (considering that you have the spaces there) like this:

```
^.*(?<=\s{4})
```

With tabs you whould have to do it like this:

```
^.*(?<=\t)
```

**Edit** - due to comment (noted by g_l):

In this case `^.*(?<=\s{1})` is enough do to the regex greedy nature and email not having any spaces within.

Comment: It looks like this modification of it works for 1+ spaces and also tabs: ^.*(?<=\s{1})

Comment: @g_l you are welcome.  Yes, in this case (you don't have spaces in email address) even lookbehind `\s{1}` will work as regexp  tries to match as much as possible - is greedy.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this, split by space and remove last element:

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\test.txt" |%{ 
$Result=$_.Trim() -split ' '
$Result[0..($Result.Length -2)] -join ' '
}
```

Comment: Nice solution.  I'm curious, how does it behave in case of tabs?  Did you try it out?

Comment: if you want split by tab you can use `t like delimiter

Comment: I see, will note it for future.  Thank you.